# How to test AOP Interceptor?

Tags: java, junit, spring-aop

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyInterceptor{
    @Around("execution(public * my.app..*(..))")
    public Object invoke(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //codes
    }
}
```

How to test the `invoke` function so that I can get the coverage % info from IntelliJ?

Comment: Is this a spring-boot project ? Will it help if you can assert the `invoke()` method call within your test?

Comment: If you go through the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html) , the video provided [shows](https://youtu.be/yNYzZvyA2ik?t=112) how to add *Packages and classes to record coverage data* . Is that what you are looking for ? Disclaimer : Not an IntelliJ user , explored out of curiosity.

Comment: Do update if you found the answer for your question. If you need a junit test case code to verify your aspect method getting triggered , I can help . For that , do update if the project is spring-boot or not .

Comment: I do not understand your question because you do not describe the problem. What have you tried? Which error occurred? Are you trying to write a unit or integration test? For example, you can write a unit test like for any other class by instantiating `MyInterceptor` and calling the advice method under test with a mocked joinpoint instance. Besides, the point of testing is not to see the coverage percentage but to make sure that method (and each line of code does inside it) the right thing. Unit-testing an aspect is no different from testing any other class, only integration testing is a bit.